# Android - NoClassDefFoundError with generated .jar from other non-android project

Tags: java, android, jar, noclassdeffounderror

Good evening everyone.

I have a non-android project with some classes I use in two different projects (one is an Android project, the other is not). I exported a .jar file from this project to use in the other projects, and it works in the non-android project.
In the Android project, when I try to intantiate a class from this .jar it gives me the NoClassDefFoundError. I tried putting the .jar into the libs folder, checking it in the Order and Import tab, putting it also in the assets folder, but none of these worked.
Does anyone know what could be happening?
Using Eclipse Kepler, Java 1.7 and Android 4.2.2

**EDIT:**

When I put a breakpoint in the line that generates the error, the logCat gives me:

```
08-15 09:32:08.970: E/dalvikvm(1051): Could not find class     'messageService.append.UserLoginAppend', referenced from method     gafit.activities.LoginActivity.attemptLogin
08-15 09:32:08.970: W/dalvikvm(1051): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1292 (LmessageService/append/UserLoginAppend;) in Lgafit/activities/LoginActivity;
08-15 09:32:08.970: D/dalvikvm(1051): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0009
08-15 09:32:08.970: D/dalvikvm(1051): VFY: dead code 0x000b-002f in Lgafit/activities/LoginActivity;.attemptLogin ()V
```

And after I resume from the breakpoint:

```
08-15 09:35:17.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1051): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-15 09:35:17.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1051): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: messageService.Message
08-15 09:35:17.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at gafit.activities.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:59)
08-15 09:35:17.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
08-15 09:35:17.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-15 09:35:17.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-15 09:35:17.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-15 09:35:17.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-15 09:35:17.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-15 09:35:17.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-15 09:35:17.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-15 09:35:17.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-15 09:35:17.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-15 09:35:17.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
08-15 09:35:17.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:638)
08-15 09:35:17.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-15 09:35:17.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1051): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: messageService.Message in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/gafit.activities-1.apk]
08-15 09:35:17.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
08-15 09:35:17.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
08-15 09:35:17.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
08-15 09:35:17.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1051):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: putting in to the libs folder works for me all the time. Can you try putting it in the libs folder cleaning the project and building again

Comment: @Peshal Just did it, and keeps giving the same error... Also closed the eclipse AND restarted the computer!

Comment: try putting the jar in both libs folder and the build path as well

Comment: When I do that the project doesnt run, gives a duplicated resource error.

Answer (score 0):

Look at LogCat output during your package installation. Sometimes Dalvik may reject some classes and not load them, you'll find records about it in log.

If you use ProGuard, it may cause some classes to be missing (for example if they are used through reflection).

Comment: I said about logcat output during package installation.And do you use ProGuard?

Answer (score 0):

Just found out what was wrong. My Android project compliance level is set to 1.6 and the project that generated the .jar was set to 1.7. 
I particularly found it very strange that nothing indicated this error...
Either way, thanks to everyone who tried to help!